# Reducing APK size that is using Mesibo

Tags: android, mesibo

Mesibo is taking 20.6Mb in size where the full app is 33Mb.
Is the size we are getting is larger than expected? Can we optimize it and reduce the size?

**Update**
Using the app bundle resolves this problem. The .so file for all architecture actually increases the size of the total app.

Comment: Use Proguard/R8 like everyone else.

Comment: I have used R8 shirnk but it doesn’t make noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 0):

that's the expected size if you are using video and voice calling features, due to various components like video codecs, audio codecs, etc.

Comment: Can I remove the emoji button in the messaging activity? Its taking around 3MB space although I don't need this.

Comment: I doubt it takes 3M but you can remove it by recompiling yourself, the complete source is here https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android

Comment: I am not asking about the button itself. The emoji keyboard is looking unnecessary to my used case. Is there any other way than recompiling?